# Arduino Ping))) Sensor suddenly stops after showing a few results

Tags: java, arduino, ping

I have a ping))) sensor (HC - SR04) which is connected correctly.

I start it up without being connected to ground (otherwise it doesn't even want to start) and it keeps writing 0 to the serial window (distance). Once I plug it in the ground pin, I get a few lines of correct distance readings and than it stops and hangs, no more results in the serial window, and the board itself seems to be in a fault state, and I need to unplug it from the USB, disconnect the ground, and then re-plug to the USB.

What can be the cause of the problem?

Code:

```
#define echoPin 2 // Echo Pin
#define trigPin 4 // Trigger Pin
#define LEDPin 13 // Onboard LED

int maximumRange = 200;  // Maximum range needed
int minimumRange = 0;    // Minimum range needed
long duration, distance; // Duration used to calculate distance
int currentDistance = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin (9600);
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT); // Use LED indicator (if required)
}

void loop() {
    /* The following trigPin/echoPin cycle is used to determine the
       distance of the nearest object by bouncing soundwaves off of it. */
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);

    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    //Calculate the distance (in cm) based on the speed of sound.
    distance = duration/58.2;

    if (distance >= maximumRange || distance <= minimumRange){
        /* Send a negative number to computer and Turn LED ON
           to indicate "out of range" */
        Serial.println("-1");
        digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
    } else {
        /* Send the distance to the computer using Serial protocol, and
           turn LED OFF to indicate successful reading. */
        Serial.println(distance);
        digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
    }

    //Delay of 50 ms before next reading.
    delay(50);
}
```

------------------------ UPDATE ------------------------------

It would seem that the problem is not with the sensor, but with the serial interface: I have attached an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) to the board and am giving it an analog value according to the distance. Once the Arduino gets "stuck", the LED keeps working correctly, so I guess the problem is with the Arduino shutting down the serial interface and stopping data transmission through the USB.

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: If I recall correctly the Ping sensor uses the same pin for "trigger" and "echo" or did they change that?

Comment: My model has two pins, one labeled Trig and the other Echo, and from schematics I've seen online they are supposed to be connected to two different ports

Comment: does `Serial.println(xxx);` expect a char pointer ("string") as its argument? In that case the line `Serial.println(distance);` can only print garbage, at least in C. (the compiler should at least issue a warning) . (in C++, there could be different println()s , depending on the argument type) Hint: maybe you could add a language tag to the question ?

Comment: It's a subset of Java, and the distance is being printed correctly to the Serial Monitor when it works

Comment: Ok, tnx. In that case it could be a buffer full condition in the serial output. Have you tried lowering the update frequency ? (or maybe: wait for the serial buffer to drain)

Comment: Thanks wildplasser! using Serial.flush() seems good so far, will wait a bit longer to make sure

Comment: Well it still gets stuck, however it seems to be surviving for a much longer time now...

Comment: Ok, so now I'm both flushing the buffer and adding a 500ms delay after writing to the serial, and it seems good, running for 5 minutes without being stuck so far. Thanks wildplasser

Comment: Something to support the theory of a faulty serial connection would be that if the `distance` really were 0 it should print "-1" due to the value of `minimumRange`. Did you try to increase the baud rate?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the sensor being stuck at zero is in this link. It's the 2nd post, by docdoc. You will need to use the NewPing library which is far better.

A working code:

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#define TRIGGER_PIN 12
#define ECHO_PIN 11
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    delay(50);
    unsigned int uS = sonar.ping();
    pinMode(ECHO_PIN,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ECHO_PIN,LOW);
    pinMode(ECHO_PIN,INPUT);
    Serial.print("Ping: ");
    Serial.print(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);
    Serial.println("cm");
}
```

Link: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=55119.15

NewPing link: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it looks like there is an interminent shortcut between the ground and the device... Or maybe there's a faulty component shortcuting to the ground. So my advice would be:

- Is the Arduino working correctly?

  - Test whether the Arduino itself works *flawlessly* without having the sensor connected (upload a echo [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch)),
- Is the sensor device working correctly?

  - Test continuity of all soldering points (look up for a shortcut bridge between the ground and a signal),
  - Test with another sensor device (if you happen to have a spare) to see if the problem persists
  - Or try the same device with another Arduino.

About your code itself, which is not, as far as I can tell, the source of your problems, I'd advice you to change the declaration of your global constants to either:

```
const uint8_t maximumRange = 200; // Maximum range needed
const uint8_t minimumRange = 0;   // Minimum range needed
const uint8_t currentDistance = 0;
```

Or use the preprocessor:

```
#define maximumRange 200  // Maximum range needed
#define minimumRange 0    // Minimum range needed
#define currentDistance = 0
```

And move:

```
long duration, distance;   // Duration used to calculate distance
```

inside your `loop()` function. Avoiding non-constant globals as much as possible is always a good idea (though not always possible with Arduino objects).

Comment: The arduino works correctly, the sensor works but only for a seemingly random periods of time which I am able to extend by increasing the delays (see updated original post)

Comment: Hi Guys.

It would seem that the problem is not with the sensor but with the serial interface: I have attached an led to the board and am giving it an analog value according to the distance, once the Arduino gets "stuck", the led keeps working correctly, so I guess the problem is with the Arduino shutting down the serial interface and stopping data transmission through the USB.

Any ideas?

Comment: then that's not the Arduino code that is faulty, but the way you handle the serial connection on the host's side. Can you give the code you're using on the host?

Comment: For the host I'm simply using the Arduino software's Serial Monitor

Comment: After doing Serial.flush() and delaying for 500ms after each Serial.println, I'm getting a lot better performance, although eventually the serial stops working

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the cause of the problem. It seems that the Arduino's serial monitor was causing the "crash", because while using a server utility that allows the Arduino output to be used in Flash ([serproxy](http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/flash)) the Arduino performs consistently and without problems.

A video of the project is *[Arduino + Ping))) Sensor - Change display in application according to distance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=220jSIRkmyc)*.